# Efficient Method to Find A Root and/or Minima of A Multivariate Polynomial With Constraints on the Variables

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, roots, maxima-minima, constraints

I have a polynomial $P(x,y,z,...)$ which has integer coefficients and real roots. I want an efficient method that is guaranteed to find a root (I only need one), and if possible, one that finds a local minima, with each of the variables $\in [0,1]$.

Comment: Not an answer, just a remark: if you initiate any kind of descent (sequential, Hooke-Jeeves, simplex, conjugate gradient...) on the *squared* polynomial, you will end-up either in a local minimum or at a zero.

Comment: @YvesDaoust So if all zeros are minima, I am guaranteed either a minima or a zero? Wouldn't this work for all functions, not just polynomials? I thought there was some special property of polynomials we could use to our advantage to make it more efficient.

Comment: Are you looking for numerical solutions / approximations or geniune solutions?

Comment: @DUO: you are quite right, this is for any smooth function. As you know, even univariate polynomials resist to analytical resolution (except for low degrees), but there are good specialized methods for root isolation and root computation. Anyway, I doubt they easily generalize to the multivariate case.

Comment: @OliverClarke Exact solutions would be nice, but numerical solutions can suffice, as long as they are close enough.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't think that's right: you could also end up going off to infinity.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: do you mean when the zero lines are unbounded ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Consider something like $(xy-1)^2 + y^2$ which has no zero, but approaches $0$ as $x \to \infty$ with $y = 1/x$.